# What is the correct posture / handle on a small Keyboard / Controller (ex: microKorg)

Tags: technique, keyboard

What's your advice on proper handling of small keyboards, like Korg's microKorg?

I'm asking because I find it particularly difficult and unnatural to play on smaller keys even when the keyboard is just sitting on my lap, or a table (which ends up being quite higher than the average keyboard height).

How do you go about making a Mod-Wheel'ed keyboard performance? Is there solid stands designed for small keyboards that could help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain; I frequently use a korg microSTATION, so I've had headaches over how awkward the microkeys are as well.

Unfortunately, the only solution is the obvious one: either raise yourself, or lower the keyboard.  In my studio, I put my keyboard on a shelf that's adjusted so that the height of the korg matches the height of my desk and other keyboards.  If I must use a normal table, I'll try to sit cross-legged to raise my body to the point where using the keyboard is comfortable.

On stage, thankfully, normal el-cheapo keyboard stands work well for me (my keyboard is somewhat longer than yours).  If I had to give you a direction to look in, I'd suggest finding a column keyboard stand.  They tend to be more expensive, but they also tend to be able to accommodate smaller keyboards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer + suggestions. This raises a small related question though - are those column keyboard stands intended to be played while standing? Or is there ways to adjust them to play sitting as well? I would think it'd be awkward to have the column in the way between your legs. And the sustain pedal placement might be tricky as well since the stands' floor-legs might get in the way.

Comment: It seems to depend on the stand; at least some of them can move high enough to allow you to play while standing.  Likewise, not all of them will sneak in between your legs, and not all of them have feet that will interfere with a footswitch (although that's definitely something that I hadn't thought of!)

Comment: Hehe no prob. I've looked at some of Ultimate-Support's stands and they look awesome and sturdy enough to hold quite a bit of weight. But I'm really wondering if they're suited for a "sit-down" performance when just using it in a home-studio. Might be good in a way though, I'd get to stretch my legs every time I play :D

Comment: Yeah, these stands in general are made with real behemoths in mind; it's gonna be overkill for your miniKORG. At the least you'll know that you can lean into it a little.  They should be fully height-adjustable, so sitting while playing probably won't be a problem.  I'd probably go out and test one before ordering online, though.